# How to include manual import() in Webpack Bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules

I am quite new to Webpack, so bear with me if thats a stupid question.

My goal is to transform my old, AMD based codebase to a ES6 Module based solution. What I am struggling with is handling dynamic `import()`s. So my app router works on a module basis, i.e. each route is mapped to a module path and then `require`d.  Since I **know** what modules will be included, I just add those dynamically imported modules to my r.js configuration and am able to build everything in a single file, with all require calls still working.

Now, I am trying to do the same with ES6 modules and Webpack. With my devmode this is no problem as I can just replace `require()` with `import()`. However I cannot get this to work with bundling. Either Webpack splits my code (and still fails to load the dynamic module anyways), or - if I use the Array format for the `entry` config, the dynamic module **is** included in the bundle but loading still fails: `Error: Cannot find module '/src/app/DynClass.js'`

This is how my Webpack config looks like:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: ['./main.js', './app/DynClass.js'],
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/")
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "/src": path.resolve(__dirname, '')
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tpl$/i,
                use: 'raw-loader',
            },
        ]
    }
};
```

So basically I want to tell Webpack: "hey, there is another module (or more) that is to be loaded dynamically and I want it to be included in the bundle"

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you looked at [webpack's explanation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) of the subject?

Comment: there are many unclear things here, how do you use `import()` in your code?
also where is `/src/app/DynClass.js` used?

Comment: @flup: yes I have. @d7my `import()` is used like this: `const module = await import(modulePath);`, so I cannot use a template here. `DynClass` is just a test-dummy being imported by the code I just mentioned. So there will be a kind of configuration object so my app-router knows what routes to match and what module to import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yeah, after much fiddling there seems to be a light at the end of the tunnel. Still, this is not a 100% solution and it is surely not for the faint of heart, as it is quite ugly and fragile. But still I want to share my approach with you:

### 1) manual parsing of my routes config

My router uses a config file looking like this:

```
import StaticClass from "/src/app/StaticClass.js";

export default {
    StaticClass: {
        match: /^\//,
        module: StaticClass
    },
    DynClass: {
        match: /^\//,
        module: "/src/app/DynClass.js"
    }
};
```

So as you can see the export is an object, with keys acting as the route id, and an object that contains the matches (regex based) and the module which should be executed by the router if the route matches. I can feed my router with both a Constructor function (or an object) for modules which are available immediatly (i.e. contained in the main chunk) or if the module value is a string, this means that the router has to load this module dynamically by using the path specified in the string.

So as I know what modules *could* be potentially loaded (but not if and when) I can now parse this file within my build process and transform the route config to something webpack can understand:

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

let routesSource = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "app/routes.js"), "utf8");

routesSource = routesSource.substr(routesSource.indexOf("export default"));
routesSource = routesSource.replace(/module:\s*((?!".*").)*$/gm, "module: undefined,");
routesSource = routesSource.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "").replace("export default", "var routes = ");

eval(routesSource);

let dummySource = Object.entries(routes).reduce((acc, [routeName, routeConfig]) => {

    if (typeof routeConfig.module === "string") {
        return acc + `import(/* webpackChunkName: "${routeName}" */"${routeConfig.module}");`;
    }

    return acc;

}, "") + "export default ''";
```

(Yeah I know this is quite ugly and also a bit brittle so this surely could be done better)

Essentially I create a new, **virtual** module where every route entry which demands a dynamic import is translated, so:

```
DynClass: {
    match: /^\//,
    module: "/src/app/DynClass.js"
}
```

becomes:

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "DynClass" */"/src/app/DynClass.js");
```

So the route id simply becomes the name of the chunk!

### 2) including the virtual module in the build

For this I use the `virtual-module-webpack-plugin`:

```
plugins: [
    new VirtualModulePlugin({
        moduleName: "./app/dummy.js",
        contents: dummySource
    })
],
```

Where `dummySource` is just a string containing the sourcecode of my virtual module I just have generated. Now, this module is pulled in and the "virtual imports" can be processed by webpack. But wait, I still need to import the dummy module, but I do not have any in my development mode (where I use everything natively, so no loaders).

So in my main code I do the following:

```
let isDev = false;
/** @remove */
isDev = true;
/** @endremove */

if (isDev) { import('./app/dummy.js'); }
```

Where "dummy.js" is just an empty stub module while I am in development mode. The parts between that special comments are removed while building (using the `webpack-loader-clean-pragma` loader), so while webpack "sees" the import for `dummy.js`, this code will not be executed in the build itself since then `isDev` evaluates to `false`. And since we already defined a virtual module with the same path, the virtual module is included while building just like I want, and of course all dependencies are resolved as well.

### 3) Handling the actual loading

For development, this is quite easy:

```
import routes from './app/routes.js';

Object.entries(routes).forEach(async ([routeId, route]) => {
    if (typeof route.module === "function") {
        new route.module;
    } else {
        const result = await import(route.module);
        new result.default;
    }
});
```

(Note that this is not the actual router code, just enough to help me with my PoC)

Well, but for the build I need something else, so I added some code specific to the build environment:

```
/** @remove */
const result = await import(route.module);
new result.default;
/** @endremove */

if (!isDev) {
    if (typeof route.module === "string") { await __webpack_require__.e(routeId); }
    const result = __webpack_require__(route.module.replace("/src", "."));
    new result.default;
}
```

Now, the loading code for the dev environment is just stripped out, and there is another loading code that uses webpack internally. I also check if the module value is a function or string, and if it is the latter I invoke the internal `require.ensure` function to load the correct chunk: `await __webpack_require__.e(routeId);`. Remember that I named my chunks when generating the virtual module? Now thats why I still can find them now!

### 4) more needs to be done

Another thing I encountered is when several dynamically loaded modules have the same dependencies, webpack tries to generate more chunks with names like `module1~module2.bundle.js`, breaking my build. To counter this, I needed to make sure that all those shared modules go into a specific named bundle I called "shared":

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        chunks: "all",
        name: "shared"
    }
}
```

And when in production mode, I simply load this chunk manually before any dynamic modules depending on it are requested:

```
if (!isDev) {
    await __webpack_require__.e("shared");
}
```

Again, this code only runs in production mode!

Finally, I have to prevent webpack renaming my modules (and chunks) to something like "1", "2" etc, but rather keep the names I just have defined:

```
optimization: {
    namedChunks: true,
    namedModules: true
}
```

Se yeah, there you have it! As I said this wasn't pretty but seems to work, at least with my simplified test setup. I really hope there aren't any blockers ahead of me when I do all the rest (like ESLint, SCSS etc)!